# Programatically set context variable to enable/disable bean validation

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, bean-validation

In my `web.xml`, I have this configuration entry:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>javax.faces.validator.DISABLE_DEFAULT_BEAN_VALIDATOR</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

However,  I don't want it to be always `true`.
I want to set it `true` or `false` in my managed bean, depending on the situation.
Is that possible?

Comment: I rollbacked your edit. You should not reuse an existing question for a new question. You should ask a new question as a new question. Your initial problem has been solved.

Comment: right, gonna set your answer as accepted, it is really a problem in hibernate validator... I found a simple solution for my case, it was just set my field with disabled=true, this way it won't fire the validation from the bean. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's the wrong way of solving the concrete problem. For that, the [`<f:validateBean>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/validateBean.html) tag should actually be used instead.

You can use it on a per-view or per-form basis, most self-documenting would be to just wrap it around the `<h:form>`. The `<h:form>` in turn can be just in a template client (and the `<f:validateBean>` thus in the master template).

```
<f:validateBean disabled="true">
    <h:form>

    </h:form>
</f:validateBean>
```

You can even use EL in there.

```
<f:validateBean disabled="#{settings.beanValidationDisabled}">
```

Comment: I think i understand, basically what i must do is, in every field of my form, put this <f:validateBean> whose "disabled" atribute is bound to a property in my managed bean that stores FALSE if i want to automatically validate, and TRUE otherwise?

Comment: That's correct. Note that, as this is done on a per-view basis, you can also put this in a master template to keep it DRY.

Comment: let me put my case here: We are developing an application that have a lot of CRUD's... Is there a way to avoid inserting this validateBean in every field of every page, and instead, doing a global validateBean in the entire form?

Comment: Uh, as answered and commented, this is done on a per-view basis, not a per-field basis. Just put a single line in your CRUD master template. Or refactor your duplicated code if you don't have any one.

Comment: By per-view-basis, what you say is that i must put the <f:validateBean> in the top of my form, as you said before? I tried that but it gave me this error: <f:validateBean> Parent not an instance of EditableValueHolder. So, it looks like this tag should be used only in editable components...

Comment: Sigh, this used to work in older Mojarra versions. I'll look what has changed.

Comment: I updated the answer. Turns out that you've actually to use it as a wrapper like `<f:view>`. That it worked in older versions was actually a bug.

Comment: That's odd! But placing the form inside the validateBean works as expected. How did you find out this solution?

Comment: Well, now i was testing and i saw a strange behavior...
When i leave an required field empty, instead of showing the actual message it shows me a weird message:(Im gonna update my message )

Comment: It's coming from JPA. It's also using bean validation during among others `EntityManager#persist()`. Re-ask the question in `[jpa][bean-validation]`. Do not reuse the current question. This is beyond JSF. Look once again at the root exception in your stack trace, it's from `javax.persistence` package (which indicates JPA problem), not from `javax.faces` package (which indicates JSF problem).